# Rails consider multiple col_sep values for CSV import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import

I want to use **comma** OR **semicolon** as :col_sep when importing CSV data in rails:

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, :col_sep => (";"), headers: true) do |row|
  user_hash = row.to_hash
  User.create!(user_hash)
end
```

works.
But putting different col_seps inline won't work:

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, :col_sep => (";",","), headers: true) do |row|
```

Is it even possible? I haven't found anything in the docu nor here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't possible. Col_sep can only accept one string. There are workarounds for this, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210070/can-i-define-more-than-one-column-separator-with-csv-parse) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832343/fastercsv-several-separators).